# Why did Maul hate Obi-Wan Kenobi after death of Satine Kryze?

Tags: star-wars, obi-wan-kenobi, darth-maul

Without going much into spoilers, we see that Maul in latter part of his life (after Clone Wars) had two main motivations : his hate against Obi-Wan Kenobi and his hate against Sith (i.e. Palpatine) . Kenobi of course cut him in two, and Palpatine killed his brother, mother and basically ruined his life.

Yet, Maul did get some revenge against Kenobi: he killed his love [Duchess Satine Kryze](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Satine_Kryze). Maul specifically said he doesn't want Obi-Wan dead, he wants to see him "share his pain". Yet, we see Maul later compulsively searching for Kenobi, almost driving himself mad. What is the reason for his continuing hate ?

Answer (score 4):

I think it probably has something to do with the fact that Kenobi chopped Maul in half in The Phantom Menance. I don't think Maul enjoyed the experience very much. I don't really see why there needs to be additional motivation on top of this.

Getting some revenge doesn't really mean he stops hating Obi Wan, particularly when as a darksider Maul is just about defined by his hate, and draws on it to fuel his power. In fact the quote about not wanting him to die implies that Maul's revenge is not complete and Maul intends to keep on tormenting Obi Wan.

Comment: As I said, Maul already got his revenge, and said he didn't want Kenobi dead but suffering. Don't read just title, read whole question ;)

Comment: @rs.29 I did, why do you think his revenge is complete? Why do you think getting revenge suddenly made him stop hating Obi Wan?

Comment: @Well, he got "perfect tool for his vengeance", so it is logical to assume his hatred would lessen, and he would not get half-mad when he hears Obi-Wan's name .

Comment: Not really, hatred doesn't really tend to  follow transactional logic like that.

Comment: In many stories that deal with the subject of revenge the act of revenge itself is generally depicted as pretty unfulfilling. Perhaps he didn't get the closure he expected from his "perfect revenge" and so instead he has made it his mission to constantly dog Obi Wan's life.